# load perl .pm module from C module .so

Tags: perl, perl-module

I'm developing a perl extension module in C, I wanted to reuse a perl module (.pm) that i wrote. I googled and found that there's a way to call a perl subroutine from C code using the pv_call function but i can't find how to load the .pm moudle without reloading the perl interpreter.
thank in advance

Comment: See [`perlembed`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlembed.html).  I'm not sure what you mean by "reloading" the interpreter, but, yes, you'll need to construct an interpreter to call a perl function.

Comment: maybe i didn't make myself clear, i have a perl extension module, which is an .so module that i call from my .pl perl code, i'd like load a .pm perl module from that .so file to the currently running interpreter. i don't wish to load another interpreter in order to load the .pm module.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`eval_pv`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlapi.html) to evaluate `use Module;`.